# Scipy minimization - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am very, very new to Python programming and I'm trying to write a code that optimizes the quantity I have to order when the Net Inventory goes below a certain value. I am getting an error, which I'm guessing has something to do with line 42 from what the terminal tells me. I don't know if anyone can help me, but I will attach my code below and the errors I'm getting, not sure if I'm doing any obvious mistakes. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: When I comment the line where I use the minimize function, I get no errors. Not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

*Code:*

```
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective (h, b, Ip, Im, NIt, s, Qt):
    return h*Ip+b*Im

def constraint1 (h, b, Ip, Im, NIt, s, Qt):
    return NIt-s

def constraint2 (h, b, Ip, Im, NIt, s, Qt):
    return Qt

def test(T, d, RT, LT, h, b, I0, s):
    i = 1
    It = [0] * T
    Qt = [0] * T
    NIt = [0] * T
    It[0] = I0 - d[0]
    Qt[0] = d[0]
    NIt[0] = I0
    while i < T:
        if (i - LT) >= 0:
            It[i] = It[i-1] - d[i] + Qt[i-LT]
        else:
            It[i] = It[i-1] - d[i]
        NIt[i] = NIt[i-1] - d[i-1] + Qt[i-1]
        if It[i-1] > 0:
            Ip = It[i-1]
            Im = 0
        if It[i-1] < 0:
            Ip = 0
            Im = It[i-1]
        if It[i-1] == 0:
            Ip = 0
            Im = 0

        x0 = [h, b, Ip, Im, NIt[i], s, Qt[i]]
        con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1(h, b, Ip, Im, NIt[i], s, 
Qt[i])}
        con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2(h, b, Ip, Im, NIt[i], s, 
Qt[i])}
        cons = [con1, con2]
        sol = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons)

        Qt[i] = sol.Qt
        i += 1
    return It, NIt, Qt

d = []
for j in range(30):
    d.append(random.randint(0, 2)) 

[It, NIt, Qt] = test(30, d, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
```

*Errors:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Fernandes/Desktop/HelloWorld/app1.py", line 52, in <module>
    [It, NIt, Qt] = test(30, d, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
  File "c:/Users/Fernandes/Desktop/HelloWorld/app1.py", line 42, in test
    sol = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons)
  File "C:\Users\Fernandes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 611, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Fernandes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 315, in _minimize_slsqp
    for c in cons['ineq']]))
  File "C:\Users\Fernandes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 315, in <listcomp>
    for c in cons['ineq']]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: This generally means you are trying to use an integer like a function, i.e. 3*(2+3) is correct as it knows to multiple product of 2+3  but 3(4+2) is wrong as it's interpreting 3 to be called as a function.  I don't have any specific advice to give on the code you provided but it looks like the module might not be receiving the data correctly.  You could also shorten the cons part to: `cons = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': [constraint1(h, b, Ip,Im, NIt[i], s,Qt[i]), constraint2(h, b, Ip, Im, NIt[i], s,Qt[i])]}` I think.

Comment: When you're specifying the constraints, you need to supply a `callable`, i.e. a function for each of the contraints' `'fun'` entry. When you write `'fun': constraint2(h, b, Ip, Im, NIt[i], s, 
Qt[i])`, however, you are giving it the **result** of evaluationg `contraint2` rather than the function itself.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply guys. When I tried to put the constraints together as Liam suggested, I got a "list object is not callable" error, rather than "int..." as before. I'm not sure what I should be doing in regards to what you mentioned hdkrgr, what would be the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

minimize expects a ndarray and you're passing it an array.
try:

```
x0 = np.array([h, b, Ip, Im, NIt[i], s, Qt[i]])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! Tried this and now it tells me "ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed" on that line. Not sure if it's because of that, but NIt and Im can be negative.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, it's np.array not np.ndarray.

Comment: Also, there's an issue with minimize and objective, sorry